# Recreating vector with template class c++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to recreate vectors using my own class called MyVector.

```
template<class T>
class MyVector{
    private:
        T *v;
        int size;
        int max;

    public:
        MyVector();
        MyVector(int n);
        MyVector(int n, int k);
        MyVector(const MyVector &l);
        void grow();
        MyVector<T>& operator=(const MyVector &lhs);
        T &operator[](unsigned int i);
        void push_back(T t);
        int capacity();
        int length();
        void reserve (int n);
        void resize(int);
};
```

i am attemping to recreate the `push_back()` function that vector has. I understand I need to create a copy of the original array with a size of size+1. but when I try:

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T t) {
    MyVector<T> *temp = v;

}
```

I get the error:

```
main.cpp: In member function âvoid MyVector<T>::push_back(T) [with T = int]â:
main.cpp:34:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:117: error: cannot convert âint*â to âMyVector<int>*â in initialization
```

I am fairly new to c++, any help is appreciated. thanks!

**EDIT**
My new push_back class

```
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(T t) {
    T *temp = v;
    v = new T[++size];
    temp[size] = t;

    for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i){
        v[i] = temp[i];
    }

    delete [] temp;
}
```

When I call and print the vector in my main program it just appends a 0 to the end of the vector.

Comment: Don't forget the destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `MyVector<T> *temp = v;` with `T` = `int`, the `v` refers to the data member that has type `int*`. You're trying to use that as an initializer for a `MyVector*`. Those are pointers to different types, incompatible pointers.

---

By the way, don't just increase the buffer by 1.

Double its size, or increase by a constant factor, so as to avoid quadratic behavior.

`std::vector` guarantees amortized linear time for `push_back`.

Comment: +1. This is s a better answer of course. My answer is more like "C#-ish" answer.

Comment: Should my class be void? It is not changing anything when I call a.push_back(10); for example. please look at edit. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a field of type `T*` to a variable of type `MyVector<T>*`. That's why you are getting the error. Change the line to:

```
T *temp = v;
```